# How I get the params of function after eval javascript with Mozilla Rhino?

Tags: javascript, java, function, rhino, param

I have some javascript files, then i'm trying in an editor to provide code completion to user. To find this function i did something like this:

```
    Context cx = Context.enter();
    try {
        Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
        cx.evaluateString(scope, jsCode, "<cmd>", 1, null);
        for (Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry: nativeObject.entrySet()){
            if (entry.getValue() instanceof Function) {
                //entry.getKey() is the name of a function...
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ...
    }
```

Now I want to get the name of params of these function too, I try to cast entry.getValue() to NativeFunction, but the method getParamCount() and getParamOrVarName() are protected.

Could anyone tell me what should I do?